# PHP - Is uniqid("") a good practical solution to generate a unique and sequential key server side?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

All,

I want to generate **server side** a user id during registration.  This id should be sequential to allow for clustered indexing.  It also needs to be unique, obviously.

To what extent can I use `uniqid("")` for this?  I am not building Google, and I assume that the risk of 2 users registering at the same microsecond is close to nill - but I have no practical experience on which to base myself.  SQL will reject duplicate id's, and I can have a loop in my php code that will keep on sending new registration entries in case of collisions / data entry failures, but that's only a good approach if collisions are rare.

Alternatively, I could add a random postcript with `uniqid("",TRUE)`, but then if 2 users register during the same microsecond, the keys can not be sequential anymore.

What is the best, practical approach to my conundrum?  Am I overthinking this?

Thanks,

JDelage

Comment: I've never had any problems with uniqid().

Comment: Use [GUID](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`uniqid` is nothing more than an interface to [`microtime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) (which is why it generates sequential IDs), and as such, it *could* be predictable and *could* create a duplicate.

> This id should be sequential to allow for clustered indexing. It also needs to be unique, obviously.  [...] Am I overthinking this?

Most databases, including MySQL, include transaction-safe sequence generators.  [MySQL's implementation, `AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html), is pretty darn primitive, but also effective.  An auto-inc primary key would ensure uniqueness and is, more importantly, *not weird*.

That said, just ensuring that the id column in the table is a primary key is complete defense against duplicate IDs.

Comment: If you do it in your code instead of let the database take care of it, you can not guarantee sanity when transactions are involved.  You will need to worry about locking, deadlocks and rollbacks.  If you let the database take care of it for you, you won't need to worry about any of that.  Doing your own identifiers outside of the database is *insanity*.  Trust me on this, I inherited a codebase that does code-side identifier generation, and dealing with the resulting edge cases is an utter nightmare.

Comment: I appreciate the real life testimony.  So you are saying that the cost of one additional db call (since I plan to use the user id as a salt for hashing the pw) is more than offset by the risks it eliminates later....

Comment: Also +1 for the "not weird".  Maybe I have been overthinking it.  Not the first time for me...  :-)

Comment: It's not the cost of the query, it's the cost of the design.  You have to fetch the next available identifier, do some work, and then do the insert.  If another process is running at the same time and happens to be doing the same thing, it may actually succeed at the insert before you do.  This means that the insert will fail with a duplicate key error, either immediately or on commit if you're in a transaction. Your code then has to clean up the mess and try fetching the next id for another attempt at the insert. The only workaround here would be an *exclusive table lock*.  (continued)

Comment: All of that work *just* to avoid using the database's built-in, transaction-safe, guaranteed-unique sequence generation mechanism?  It's totally not worth the effort.  If you need the identifier to perform password salting, make the password field nullable and perform an update post-insert with the salted password.  A null password can also be a handy "you aren't allowed to log in" flag. (My inherited codebase does it's own identifier generation because of multi-master replication, which did not play well with auto-increment before MySQL 5.x.)

Comment: I had not thought about that.  Very interesting, thank you.  Can you expand on the null password as "can't login" flag?  What's the user case for this?

Comment: Let's say that these user accounts can be disabled, from an administrative point of view. Think of being banned from a site. Or being fired. One way to store the "account is active" state would be to have a flag just for the purpose. The same effect can be achieved by simply reusing the password field. A `null` password will always prevent the user from logging in, after all. Keep in mind that this is just a convenience thing for this *specific* case.

Answer (score 6):

In database theory it is assumed that no events happen at the same time quantum, in your case microseconds. Many database concepts built on this presumption.

I didn't hear `uniqid` generated same hashes on sequential requests. Because, its seed is microseconds and most probably your processor executes a machine instruction more or less in a microsecond, there is too much time between processing of two requests (even they are running concurrently in single CPU).

If you think that you may have collisions in 512-bit hash (32 hex characters), then you can build your own digest function which utilizes more characters from the alphabet and punctuations, because as I said before, we solved  the time seed issue, all you should worry about must be to fully utilize seed and lower probability of collision.

If you want  to be sure, you can serve requests in a mutually exclusive way and then after you serve for a request, you can insert a row to database (let's say a user registration, you insert a user record to the users table) and use PHP function `mysql_insert_id()` then you can proceed to serving other request so that you can use recently inserted record id as a seed (which will be always different for any two consecutive requests).

**Clarification about last paragraph upon request:**
as I said before nothing happens at the same time in the databases, according to serving theory. Always, one of them served first. Therefore you can start a transaction in database. Let's say you are registering a new user. You'll say `INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)`. There you go, you have inserted a new user. While this database query happens, you should implement a Mutual Exclusion Lock (`mutex`), I don't know how it is done in PHP. If you implement a mutex, second request will wait until you finish your processing with first request. After the row is inserted on database, you use `$i = mysql_insert_id()` to retrieve ID of just inserted row! When you say `$i+1` for the ID of second user, it will be unique. Because first user was let's say `300`, then the second user will be `301`.

In fact, database auto increment IDs are always unique. If you want to have a unique string hash for the user, here's a method.

1. Insert user. (query stated above)
2. Get user's id with `$i = mysql_insert_id()`
3. Then encrypt this id with some digest algorithm such as `$d = strrev(md5($i))`
4. Then put this value on `unique_id` column of `users` table with an `UPDATE user SET unique_id='$d' where id=$i` query.
5. There you go, you have unique string for everyone.

Comment: Great answer, thank you.  Was especially interested in reading about the processor speed thing.

Comment: You're welcome. You can read more about uniqueness and collisions on digested hashes or random sequences on the web. This is also an academic field.

Comment: If you have more time, I would love some clarification on your last paragraph at some point.

Comment: I think any modern processor with clock speeds >1GHz would be able to execute a single machine instruction on the order of _nanoseconds_ instead of microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to UUID. It's not an incrementing number and should always be unqiue. However, do not use the function UUID in an INSERT statement. It can lead to problems.